# How can I use django-jfu with a ImageField and a FK?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use [django-jfu](https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu) to multiupload images, but I have a problem. I want to handle a foreign key dynamically (via url or something), but I can't think of anything.

I have the following models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Picture(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
```

According to django-jfu, you have to specify a "upload" view to call from the template via template tag. This is my upload view:

```
@require_POST
def upload(request):

    event = Event.objects.get(id=26)
    file = upload_receive(request)
    instance = Picture(image = file, event = event)
    print instance
    instance.save()

    basename = os.path.basename(instance.image.path)

    file_dict = {
        'name' : basename,
        'size' : file.size,

        'url': settings.MEDIA_URL + basename,
        'thumbnailUrl': settings.MEDIA_URL + basename,

        'deleteUrl': reverse('jfu_delete', kwargs = { 'pk': instance.pk }),
        'deleteType': 'POST',
    }

    return UploadResponse(request, file_dict)
```

Right now, as a test, it only saves pictures to event with id=26, but how can I handle it dynamically? This is the view and template where I'm calling the template tag:

view

```
def add_pictures_to_event(request, event_id):
    return render(request, 'add_pictures_to_event.html')
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load jfutags %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Photo upload</h2>

    {% jfu %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, the view `add_pictures_to_event`, gets the `request` and the `id` of the event, but I cant seem to pass it to the upload view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I looked at different django versions of jQuery File Upload but stuck with Alem's jfu but with the [changes](https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu/pull/36) from Thomas Willson to make it work in 1.9. My solution might not be the best but I could not find an other way.

I assume you already created an event and then add images to it.

media_upload_form.html is in my projects static directory. I used the [UPLOAD_FORM_EXTRA](https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu#user-content-html-components) block to add a hidden formfield with the current event_id:

```
{% block UPLOAD_FORM_EXTRA %}
        <input type="hidden" name="currentevent" value="{{instance.pk}}">
{% endblock %}
```

I assume you have the view from the docs. I changed in the beginning of the uploadview:

```
file = upload_receive( request )

event_instance = get_object_or_404(Event, id=request.POST['currentevent'])
instance = Picture( file = file, event=event_instance)
instance.save()
```

It is probably against all django rules but it works. If anyone has a better solution I like to know too. FormSets maybe?